# Iterating a JSON return properly

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a strange problem with my script. I am getting a JSON result set and want to iterate it and then display in a div. I checked fiddler and I can see the entire set being returned like the set below

```
[{"EPubID":71,"SerialID":1,"PartnerID":343,"Partner":"Aberdeen, City of ","PublicationTitle":"Uploading multiple files test","AuthFirstName":null,"AuthMiddleName":null,"AuthLastName":null,"AuthFullName":null,"PublicationYear":2011,"SubmitterEmail":null,"VolumeNumber":null,"Issue":null,"AlreadyInCatalog":false,"InCatalog":"No","Status":"D","Notes":"testing multiple file uploads","IsMonograph":false,"Monographed":"No","SubmittedDate":"\/Date(1317913458810)\/","SubmittedBy":"admin","ApprovedDate":"\/Date(1317914842263)\/","ApprovedBy":"admin","SubmittingPartnerID":0,"OriginalRefId":"343-71","SerialName":"None","URL":null,"InfoRecordID":0,"LastModified":"\/Date(-62135568000000)\/","IsSerial":false,"Approved":false,"Delete":false,"Pending":false,"files":null},{"EPubID":72,"SerialID":19,"PartnerID":26,"Partner":"Digital Archives","PublicationTitle":"testing multiple file uploads ","AuthFirstName":null,"AuthMiddleName":null,"AuthLastName":null,"AuthFullName":null,"PublicationYear":2001,"SubmitterEmail":null,"VolumeNumber":"1","Issue":"1","AlreadyInCatalog":false,"InCatalog":"No","Status":"A","Notes":"this should work","IsMonograph":false,"Monographed":"No","SubmittedDate":"\/Date(1317915134767)\/","SubmittedBy":"admin","ApprovedDate":"\/Date(1317915430627)\/","ApprovedBy":"admin","SubmittingPartnerID":0,"OriginalRefId":"26-72","SerialName":"Fake Test Serial","URL":null,"InfoRecordID":0,"LastModified":"\/Date(-62135568000000)\/","IsSerial":false,"Approved":false,"Delete":false,"Pending":false,"files":null}]
```

The problem is my script is only displaying the first item returned and nothing else. Here is my script.

```
function SearchExistingEpubs() {
    var title = $("input#PublicationTitle").val();

    $('#Results').hide();
    $("div#SearchResults").innerHTML = '';
    $.getJSON('/EPub/SearchExistingEpubs/' + title, null, function (data) {
        var items = [];
        var found = false;
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            found = true;
            $("div#SearchResults").empty();
            $("div#SearchResults").append("Title: " + val.PublicationTitle + " Owning Partner: " + val.Partner + " Year: " + val.PublicationYear) ;
            $('#Results').show();
        });
        if (!found) {
            $("div#SearchResults").empty();
            //$("div#SearchResults").html('');
            $("div#SearchResults").append("No documents found");
            $('#Results').show();
            //$('#Results').slideUp(10000);
            $('#Results').animate({height:'toggle'},10000);
            //$('#Results').fadeOut(10000);
        }
        //$('#Results').show();
    });        
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're wiping out the contents of the div in each iteration of the loop with your call to `empty()`:

```
$.each(data, function (key, val) {
    found = true;
    $("div#SearchResults").empty();  // <------ REMOVE this line
    $("div#SearchResults").append("Title: " + val.PublicationTitle + " Owning Partner: " + val.Partner + " Year: " + val.PublicationYear) ;
    $('#Results').show();
});
```

But doing dom updates in a loop is not usually a good idea.  Why not build up your string and do *one* dom update:

```
var content = '';
$.each(data, function (key, val) {
    found = true;
    content += "Title: " + val.PublicationTitle + " Owning Partner: " + val.Partner + " Year: " + val.PublicationYear;
});
$("div#SearchResults").append(content);
$('#Results').show();
```

Comment: I've been downvoted for suggesting dom updates in a loop before - the community is a good teacher :)

Comment: @samack - no prob - best of luck

Answer (score 1):

In your `.each` loop you're calling `$("div#SearchResults").empty();` this will clear any content you've previously appended to this div.

Try the following:

```
function SearchExistingEpubs() {
  var title = $("input#PublicationTitle").val();
  $('#Results').hide();
  $("div#SearchResults").empty();
  $.getJSON('/EPub/SearchExistingEpubs/' + title, null, function (data) {
    $("div#SearchResults").empty();
    var items = [];
    if (data.length) {
      $.each(data, function (key, val) {
        $("div#SearchResults").append("Title: " + val.PublicationTitle + " Owning Partner: " + val.Partner + " Year: " + val.PublicationYear);
      });
      $('#Results').show();
    } else {
      $("div#SearchResults").append("No documents found");
      $('#Results').show();
      $('#Results').animate({height:'toggle'},10000);
    }
  });        
};
```